# QProcess Killed or Successfully finished

Tags: qt, kill, qprocess

How can I know if a Qprocess has successfully finished its execution or has been killed forcefully using process.kill()? In both the case the exitstatus() is normalExit.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any specific function call, if that's what you're looking for. You didn't mention what platform you're using, but in the case of Linux, calling kill() sends a message to the process for it to terminate, so as far as the Process is concerned, everything is ok when it finished.

What you may be able to do though is subclass QProcess and overload the kill function to set a boolean value which you can check when the QProcess emits finished().

Answer (score 0):

[QProcesss::exiStatus()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#exitStatus) will give you this information. If the QProcess exits normally it will return Normal Exit or if the process was killed  it will return Crash Status.

You can also check the [QProcess::exitCode()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#exitCode) to see the exact exit code for that process.

The following is a Linux example if a process is killed with SIGKILL.

```
QProcess subproc;
// Run the process here
subproc.waitForExit();
qDebug() << "Status: " << subproc.exitStatus()
qDebug() << "Code: " << subproc.exitCode()
```

While the sub-process is running run the following Linux command:

```
kill -9 <subproc PID>
```

Then the following is printed:

```
Status: CrashExit
Code: 9
```

Without using the kill command on the sub-process the following is output is observed:

```
Status: NormalExit
Code: 0
```

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour on Qt4, the exit code returned is still zero for the `CrashExit`. Also, from the Qt5 documentation, the exit code is not reliable unless the status is `NormalExit`. 

I needed to know the exit code for a given `QProcess`, but apparently it provides no such interface.